# Regex: how to deal with brackets and back slashes? Example: make "[{\ into [{

Tags: javascript, regex

I am converting a csv file into JSON, and the converter adds `"` at the beginning of lines, and also adds a `\` to quotes.

So, if my CSV file has an array like

```
"items": [{"name":"item 1"...
```

the resulting JSON from the converter is:

```
"items": "[{\"name\":\"item 1\"...
```

I need the JSON to look like the original CSV entry.

So, how do I change `"[{` to `[{` ?

Note: I can't just remove quotes everywhere, as they are correct in certain spots. So I need to just remove quotes when they are followed by these specific characters, so only remove `"[{`

And how do I remove the `\` everywhere they appear?

**EDIT**
Some of the comments and answers have mentioned maybe there is a better way to convert the CSV into a JSON file. In my case, I have data in excel that I need to ultimately be readable by a Lambda function, so I expect I need a way to convert excel to JSON. I have posted a separate question asking for assistance on that topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60580598/best-way-to-convert-excel-file-into-a-json-file) .

Comment: You're converting to JSON multiple times, so it's escaping the quotes in the embedded JSON. You probably shouldn't be doing that. Show your code and we'll explain how to fix it.

Comment: The conversion itself is not being done in my code. I have data in a CSV that I need to convert into a JSON file. I am doing that with an online converter. Once I have the JSON file, my code parses it. So the question is how to parse the JSON to remove what I have noted in the question.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should try to generate the correct json format, so that you don't have to go through this issue at all.

However if you have no control over the output of the json data that you're getting, you can simply remove the `\"` parts by using this `regexp`:

`your_json_var.toString().replace(/\"/g,'');`

Where `your_json_var` contains the returned data.

```js
your_json_var = '"items": "[{\"name\":\"item 1\"...';

var new_var = your_json_var.toString().replace(/\"/g,'');

console.log(new_var);
```

Comment: In my case, I have a CSV file, and I need my code to be able to read it as JSON. The easiest solution I have found is to just convert the CSV file to a JSON file with an online converter. The items I note above are the JSON that result from that converter.

Comment: @9gt53wS i have added code example for you, i hope it helps. however i still believe that you should add logic at import time for proper data type

Comment: Thanks. I'll test out the code. Just to be clear, after running the converter, I have the JSON file in hand, and then my code has to run it. To correct the formatting, I plan to use the regex like we are discussing. How is that different than "add logic at import time"?

Comment: we should minimize using regexp for peformance purpose mainly. test this out though and see if it serves the purpose. however you should post the code you're using for csv to json and also exact starting lines of csv file too so that we can help you with it

Comment: I see. Performance is actually very important here, so if regex is bad for that I'll find a different way.

Comment: In terms of the "code" for CSV. I am entering data manually into an excel file--that's where the data is housed. I then need a way for my code to read that excel data as JSON. Is there a better way than converting the CSV into a JSON file with a converter?

Comment: Here's an example converter: http://convertcsv.com/csv-to-json.htm

Comment: Regarding your code: it works to remove the \ . But it leaves in the quotes in front of the array beginning. I need to have "[{ become [{ . Are you able to provide code for that?

Comment: @9gt53wS please add exact start of string or paste it in pastebin and send the link, and also upvote and select the answer if it's correct

Comment: The string is like in the question, specifically: "[{\"name\":  ... And I want it to be: [{"name"...  Your code does not seem to remove the quotes at the beginning of the string.

Comment: @9gt53wS i have updated the code, please check it now

Answer (score 0):

You could do this
Let stringJson=JSON.stringify(myjson)
Let clearJson = JSON.parse(stringJson.replace(/\"[{/g, '[{').replace(/\/g,'')

Comment: doesn't work. I get "Unterminated regular expression literal". I also get notes about syntax errors in various spots.